How to restrict the area of a react-rnd Rnd window that is draggable?
I put some ChartJS graphs in Rnd and it's mostly great but if I want to pan around in the graph, it also moves the window. Here's an example...

My current code is
    <>
      <Rnd
        style={style}
        default={{
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          width: 600,
          height: 200,
        }}
      >
        <Chart type="line" ref={chartRef} data={data} options={options} />
      </Rnd>
    </>

What I want to do is have it so that it will ignore the area of its div that is overlaid by the canvas. I think then I'd have to add another child to Rnd to be like a windows top bar and only dragging that drags the window.
The only thing I can think of is having a useEffect tracking the mouse position over the canvas so when the mouse is over the canvas it's true and false otherwise and then have disableDragging take that state variable. I haven't tried that yet because I'm hoping there's a better way as I suspect that approach would come with a lot of hair with all the rerenders that would cause.

Here's the disableDragging approach. The first thing is to put a small Box (I'm using MUI, so just a div really) at the top of the Rnd and then put a mouse listener on the Box so that anytime the mouse goes over the box or leaves the box, it sets a State variable. Use that State variable for the disableDragging parameter in Rnd. I'm not noticing real world performance issues with my small site but it seems like the rerenders induced by moving the mouse are not the best way.

const handleMouseMove = (
  e: MouseEvent,
  chartRef: MutableRefObject<null | HTMLDivElement>,
  setDisableDragging: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>
) => {
  if (
    chartRef.current != undefined &&
    'getBoundingClientRect' in chartRef.current
  ) {
    const rect = (chartRef.current as HTMLDivElement).getBoundingClientRect()
    const isInChart =
      e.clientX >= rect.left &&
      e.clientX <= rect.right &&
      e.clientY >= rect.top &&
      e.clientY <= rect.bottom
    setDisableDragging(!isInChart)
  }
}
const Graph: FC<GraphTprops> = () => {

  const [disableDragging, setDisableDragging] = useState(false)
  const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    // Add global mousemove listener
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', (e: MouseEvent) =>
      handleMouseMove(e, containerRef, setDisableDragging)
    )

    return () => {
      // Clean up listener on component unmount
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', (e: MouseEvent) =>
        handleMouseMove(e, containerRef, setDisableDragging)
      )
    }
  }, [containerRef])

  const chartRef = useRef(null)

  const options = ...
 
  const data = ...

  return (
    <>
      <Rnd
        disableDragging={disableDragging}
      >
        <Box
          ref={containerRef}
          sx={{
            height: '15px',
            width: '100%',
            display: 'block',
            top: '0',
            left: '0',
          }}
        />
        <Chart type="line" ref={chartRef} data={data} options={options} />
      </Rnd>
    </>
  )
}

